# What does this error mean?

Tags: errors

This is my first attempt in using Tex and I am already drafting my Thesis in this, but so far so good. However, I have lately encountered this error, and I cannot figure out what this means...
help please...[image]

```
%LINE 16
\begin{document}
\frontmatter      % Begin Roman style (i, ii, iii, iv...) page numbering

% Set up the Title Page







_____________________________
% Chapter 1

\chapter{Introduction} % Write in your own chapter title
\label{Chapter1}
\lhead{Chapter 1. \emph{Introduction}} % Write in your own chapter title to set the page header
\section{Background}

\section{Motivation}

\section{Research Aim and Objectives}

\section{Research Approach}

\section{Thesis Structure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This error is usually due to fragile commands in section titles. An example of code is needed.

Comment: Welcome! It may mean you have an unmatched opening curly bracket. Or TeX thinks you do. Start by looking on line 16 of `Thesis.tex` but sometimes the line number won't be very accurate. Probably it is in your preamble, though. If you post code which we can use to reproduce the error, we can help you find it.

Comment: Your .aux file is corrupt, delete thesis.aux and try again.

Comment: This is due to a corrupted aux file. Just remove the file `Thesis.aux`. (Most LaTeX text editors have this somewhere in the menus).

Comment: @yo' -- but since this seems to be a problem related to something that was in the `.aux` file, it might happen again (on a "second" run).  egreg's pointer to section titles is a reasonable clue, and it is almost certainly in a section title recently added.

Comment: Yes, I added several sections and subsections recently (still have to fill in the info though). I deleted the .aux file now.

What code would you like me to copy-paste? Wouldn't that then mean all my thesis would be here (and be caught by plagiarism check?)

Comment: @Manoj if you can make the smallest example you can that has the problem (probably just the section headings needed) then probably you can replace the words with `abc` and still show the same error. so no need to show any secrets, but basically if you comment out your section headings and remove the aux file then re-run latex, it should work, put the headings back one at a time until it breaks, and that will show the problem.

Comment: %This is from the Chapter 1 file
%Shall I also paste code from the thesis.tex file?

% Chapter 1

\chapter{Introduction} % Write in your own chapter title
\label{Chapter1}
\lhead{Chapter 1. \emph{Introduction}} % Write in your own chapter title to set the page header
\section{Background}

\section{Motivation}

\section{Research Aim and Objectives}

\section{Research Approach}

\section{Thesis Structure}

Comment: %Line 16
\begin{document}
\frontmatter   % Begin Roman style (i, ii, iii, iv...) page numbering

% Set up the Title Page
\title  {...}
\authors  {\texorpdfstring
            {\href{http://...}{...}}
            {...}
            }
\addresses  {\groupname\\\deptname\\\univname}  % Do not change this here, instead these must be set in the "Thesis.cls" file, please look through it instead
\date       {\today}
\subject    {}
\keywords   {...}

Comment: @Manoj Please, use the `edit` button below the question text and add your code there. This is impossible to parse.

Comment: Done. Thanks.

So, the first bit is the line 16. It worked fine with the thesis template that I used. The second part is the additional file called Chapter 1 and the last bit is the screenshot of the file structure.

Comment: Thanks, But, that is how it is formatted on my file. Apologies for my copy/paste.

Comment: @egreg A fragile command does not explain, why the `.aux` file stops at the end of `\@writefile{...}{\contentsline{s` in the middle of presumably `section`, `subsection` or `subsubsection` (and the unknown first argument of `\@writefile` is probably `toc`).

Answer (score 4):

I think yo' is right with the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262491/what-does-this-error-mean/262502#comment629493_262491), that the `.aux` file is truncated:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Hello World}
\end{document}
```

After `pdflatex test.tex` the `.aux` file is:

```
\relax
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Hello World}{1}}
```

Then the `.aux` file is edited in an editor to truncate it to:

```
\relax
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {s
```

Running again:

```
pdflatex -file-line-error test.tex
```

gives the error in the same format as in the question:

```
) (./test.aux)
Runaway argument?
{\contentsline {s
./test.tex:2: File ended while scanning use of \@writefile.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.2 \begin{document}

?
```

The `\@writefile` command starts on line 2 in file `test.aux`, but the error is detected after the file end, thus the file name is shown as `test.tex`.

Back to the question, the error occurs during the first read of the `.aux` file. The `.aux` file is truncated at line 16.

Suspicion: The file size of the `.aux` file is just a sector with 512 bytes. Thus the write cache did not get flushed at the probably abnormal end of the previous LaTeX run.

Deleting the `.aux` file and running LaTeX again should fix the issue, when the run is not aborted due to a fatal error.